# Only the first jQuery tooltip() is showing, why?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I've tried this code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    $("[data-preview]" ).each(function(){

        $(this).tooltip({ content: function(){
                return '<img src="/img/hover/'+$(this).attr("data-preview")+'.png" />';
        }, track: true, tooltipClass: "hoverpreview" });

    });
});
```

And also this code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
      $("[data-preview]" ).tooltip({ content: function(){
        return '<img src="/img/hover/'+$(this).attr("data-preview")+'.png" />';
      }, track: true, tooltipClass: "hoverpreview" });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="productnav doors">  
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/products/f-series" class="active" alt="F-SERIES" title="F-SERIES" data-preview="thumb-fseries">F-SERIES</a></li>
        <li><a href="/products/dw-series" class="" alt="DW SERIES" data-preview="thumb-dwseries">DW SERIES</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But it will only show the first tooltip.

Comment: can you show the html?

Comment: @LioraHaydont sure, I've updated the question to add the html code.

Comment: if you add a console.log in your each function, is something logged 2 times of only once?

Comment: If I run console.log($(this).attr("data-preview")); inside the each() function I get: 'thumb-fseries' then 'thumb-dwseries'.

Comment: Hum. Try putting `$(this).attr("data-preview")` in a variable at the start of the loop? and then use the variable. I wonder if it could be that $(this) doesn't refer to the same thing.

Comment: I tried adding `var $this = $(this);
   var $preview = $this.attr("data-preview");` and no dice. Still only the first one executes.

Comment: if you add somewhere `'<img src="/img/hover/thumb-dwseries.png" />'`, does it show? Maybe it's working but the image is not showing because there is a typo

Comment: I wasn't that either. I figured it out. Apparently tooltip() doesn't work without the element having a title tag, even if it's provided content. Doh!